# Display message in primefaces button action

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I have a datatable with 2 text columns and a button:

```
<p:dataTable var="car" value="#{myClass.cars}" editable="true" editMode="cell"
    <p:column headerText="Column1">
        <p:cellEditor>
            <f:facet name="output"><h:outputText value="#{car.col1}" /></f:facet>
            <f:facet name="input">
                <h:inputText value="#{car.col1}" >
                    <p:ajax event="blur" />
                </h:inputText>    
            </f:facet>
        </p:cellEditor>
    </p:column>

    <p:column headerText="Column2">
        <p:cellEditor>
            <f:facet name="output"><h:outputText value="#{car.col2}" /></f:facet>
            <f:facet name="input">
                <h:inputText value="#{car.col2}" >
                   <p:ajax event="blur" />
                </h:inputText>    
            </f:facet>
        </p:cellEditor>
    </p:column>
</p:dataTable>

<p:messages for="messages4" id="messages" showDetail="true" autoUpdate="true" closable="true" />

<p:commandButton value="Next" action="#{myClass.nextAction}" />

public void nextAction() {
    if (car.col1 or car.col2 not valid) {
        FacesMessage msg = new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR,
                            "Invalid summary", "Invalid message");                          
        FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage("messages4", msg);
// Also tried same problem with FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, msg);
    }
}
```

I had 2 issues:

(1) If I enter a value in column1 or column2 and then straight after click on the "Next" button then the value is not set when queried in the nextAction(). The value is set if I click in another cell after entering value and then click on next button. I have fixed this issue by adding a dummy ajax blur event.

(2) I want to display a message (information, warning or error) using FacesMessage in nextAction(). The problem is that the message is not displayed if I click on next button straight after entering a value in column1 or column2. But the message is displayed if I click in another cell after entering a value and then click on next button.

It seems that these 2 issues are related but haven't managed to find a solution. Anybody can help?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]

Comment: And are you using IE? Tried with Firefox or Chrome?

Comment: @Jasper de Vries: I have added code for nextAction()

Comment: @Kukeltje: I get the same problem when run on IE, Firefox and Chrome

Comment: @amah: adding code-snippets does not make it a [mcve]... Please read it and also http://www.stackoverflow.com/tags/jsf/info.

Comment: I have made a mistake when i said that message is not displayed in issue number (2) above. The message does appear but it stays only for very very short time and then goes away - it just flashes and then disappears. You have to concentrate very hard because the message is visible for a very short time.